# "Рок более не довлеет над ним" — так говорить правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Довлеть - это значит давить? Но оказывается, вовсе нет. Тем не менее это  просторечное понимание книжного слова закрепилось в нашей речи, и что теперь делать?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Есть в русском языке глагол - довлеть, значение которого со временем менялось. Изначально  "довлеть" - это "являться достаточным, удовлетворять", потом - "подобает, надлежит". Получается что-то вроде "соответствует заданному критерию, то есть тому, как что должно быть".

Примеры

Довлеет дневи злобы его  (довольно для каждого дня своей заботы). Стиху довлеет (подобает, надлежит) царское убранство. Природа сама себе довлеет. Творческая мысль сама себе довлеет (независима, сама определяет критерии соответствия, самодовлеющая).

2) Но вот русское просторечие конца XIX в. закрепляет за неверно понятым глаголом "довлеть" новое значение: преобладать, господствовать. Ясное дело: довлеть - это значит давить. И что нам теперь с этим наследством делать?

3) Словарь на Грамоте.ру

ДОВЛЕТЬ, 1. Устар. книжн. Быть достаточным, удовлетворять. Созданный им мир довлел только ему одному. 2. над кем (чем). Разг. Господствовать, тяготеть над кем-, чем-л. Прошлое довлеет над моей жизнью.

4) Таким образом, образованность человека можно вычислить по тому, в каком значении он употребляет это слово  (если вообще его употребляет).
Обычно это выглядит так: "бизнес довлеет над твоей личной жизнью, рок более не довлеет над ним,  издательский процесс довлеет над литературным".

Но настоящие интеллектуалы не ошибаются, и с правильно употребленным словом "довлеть"  речь звучит очень красиво и поэтично: Охапку дров свалив у камелька, Вари пшено, ― и час тебе довлеет (И. Г. Эренбург). Так отчего ж до сих пор этот город довлеет Мыслям и чувствам моим по старинному праву? (И. А. Бродский).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Источник: Грамота ру.

Довлеть

Вопрос
Как правильно употреблять глагол довлеть? Корректно ли его использование с предлогом на в значении «давить», «тяготеть»?

Глагол довлеть произошел от унаследованного русским литературным языком старославянского глагола довлети, означавшего 'быть достаточным, хватать'. В первоначальном значении этот глагол употребляется в евангельском выражении довлеет дневи злоба его, переводимом 'хватает на каждый день своей заботы, довольно для каждого дня своей заботы' (отсюда и устойчивое сочетание злоба дня - повседневная забота, нужда данного момента, требующая немедленного удовлетворения; потом и прилагательное злободневный).

Слово довлеет встречается и в другом устойчивом выражении - довлеть самому (самой) себе, означающем 'зависеть в своем существовании и развитии только от себя', например: природа сама себе довлеет. Отсюда прилагательное самодовлеющий - 'достаточно значительный сам по себе, имеющий вполне самостоятельную ценность'.

Однако в XX веке у глагола довлеть возникло совершенно новое значение - 'тяготеть, преобладать, господствовать'. Вот как об этом пишет Л. Успенский в книге "Слово о словах":

<<Нам, особенно не знающим древнеславянского языка, "довлеть" по звучанию напоминает "давить", "давление", - слова совсем другого корня. В результате этого чисто внешнего сходства произошла путаница. Теперь даже очень хорошие знатоки русского языка то и дело употребляют (притом и в печати) глагол "дОвлеть" вместо сочетания слов "оказывать дАвление":

"Гитлеровская Германия довлела над своими союзниками".

"Над руководителями треста довлеет одна мысль: как бы не произошло затоваривания..."

В этих случаях "довлеет" значит уже "давит", "висит", "угнетает", - все что угодно, только не "является достаточным".

По поводу этого обстоятельства в нашей прессе возникли бурные споры. Писатель Ф. Гладков опротестовал подобное понимание слова, совершенно справедливо считая его результатом прямой ошибки, неосведомленности в славянском языке. Казалось бы, он совершенно прав.

Однако посыпались возражения. Старое древнеславянское значение слова забылось, говорили многие, утвердилось новое. Какое нам дело до того, что´ "довлеть" значило во дни Гостомысла? Теперь оно значит другое, и смешно возражать против этого. Подобные превращения происходят в языке постоянно...>>

Таким образом, новое значение глагола довлеть постепенно прижилось в русском языке. Сейчас  говорить довлеть над кем-то в значении 'господствовать, тяготеть' допустимо, употребление соответствует норме. Но управление еще испытывает колебания в стилистическом плане. Так, довлеть над кем-чем отмечено как нейтральное в "Толковом словаре русского языка" С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой, но с пометой "разговорное" в "Большом толковом словаре русского языка" под редакцией С. А. Кузнецова.

Подробно об истории этого слова можно прочитать в книге: В. В. Виноградов. История слов. М., 1994.

Вот полное [письмо Ф. Гладкова президенту Академии наук СССР](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/44/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Хотя словарь ошибок такое употребление считает неправильным.

Comment: Вы так любите минусовать ответы, прям удовольствие получаете. Можете и дальше отслеживать мои ответы и минусовать их.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за информацию. Я присоединяюсь к Гладкову, у меня довлеть-давить тоже вызывает мучительный протест. Возникает желание организовать Всероссийское общество защиты слов и внести подобные слова  в Красную книгу России (по аналогии с  животными, растениями и грибами).

Comment: Нет, не люблю. Но буду делать. Vera, а в чем именно вы присоединяетесь? Я вообще ничего предметного из этого письма не уяснил. Информации не больше, чем в надписи на сарае.

Answer (score 2):

А ничего не делать. такое процесс называется переосмыслением, он закономерен в языке.

Это не единственное слово, получившее новое значение из-за непонимания. Классический пример - "нелицеприятный". Оно вообще дважды изменило значение с "неприятный лицом", через "не принимающий лицо" (считающееся ныне правильным), до современного разговорного "неприятный лицу". Не откатывать же назад?

Еще - будировать. От французского "сердиться". Сейчас нормально - поднимать вопрос, возбуждать.

Можно еще вспомнить. Да вообще все новые значения так или почти так появляются.

Плюс еще масса устоявшихся идиом... Вот и считайте такое употребление идиомой, что ли...

Другой вопрос, насколько правомерно использовать новоявленное значение... В данном случае мне кажется, говорить об утрате старого и приобретении нового норматива несколько преждевременно.

Answer (score 1):

> > Но настоящие интеллектуалы не ошибаются, и с правильно употребленным словом "довлеть" речь звучит очень красиво и поэтично

При чем тут интеллектуалы? Далее вы привели стихотворные строки, причём не самых плохих поэтов, и сравнили их с каким-то издательским процессом... Жульничество-с!

Comment: Обычно это выглядит так: "бизнес довлеет над твоей личной жизнью, рок более не довлеет над ним, издательский процесс довлеет над литературным". Не было сравнения, тысячу извинений.

Comment: Как же не было, когда Vera именно сравнила.

Answer (score 0):

Просторечное понимание книжного слова закрепилось в нашей речи, и что теперь делать?

Иногда клин клином вышибают. Можно поступать так — намеренно и непринуждённо сталкивать эти слова в речи и на письме: довлело-довлело и придавило; довлело без давления; рок более не довлеет,— попса не дала себя выдавить на обочину.